# How do I create a tarball that only contains the files, and not a directory with the files?

Tags: terminal, console, tar

I have a folder foo containing 3 files.
How do I create a tarball containing only the files. Instead of foo/ with those three files. Using the terminal.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash and GNU tar:

```
shopt -s dotglob
cd /path/to/foo && tar -cvf /tmp/file.tar -- *
```

From `man bash`:

> `dotglob`: If  set,  bash includes filenames beginning with a `.' in the results of pathname expansion.

Comment: This works on bash, and as long as it is installed I can go to bash to tar something. Do you know how to set a similar setting on zsh? shopt doesn't work there.

Comment: This should work wirh zsh: `setopt cshnullglob; cd /path/to/foo && tar -cvf /tmp/file.tar -- .* *`